# How to retrieve DB credentials from external file for Liquibase config

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I have a Spring Boot application which runs in Azure Kubernetes. The application uses Liquibase (Liquibase-Core 4.4.3) to create and amend database tables for the application on start up. For security reasons the application has different DB credentials to the Liquibase user and the Liquibase user credentials are added via the application.properties file as per below using environment variables:

```
spring.liquibase.url=${env_db_connection_url}
spring.liquibase.user=${env_db_lb_username}
spring.liquibase.password=${env_db_lb_password}
```

We add the credentials using this method with environment variables as the credentials are different depending on the environment (e.g. UAT, production) the app is being deployed to and this allows the pipeline to handle the differences without any changes being necessary to the code.

Our security team want us to stop using environment variables and so we are moving to using csi drivers for any sensitive information. This effectively creates something similar to an external properties file which sits outside the application but within the same container.

However, I am now having trouble resolving the db credentials for Liquibase and I don't know the best method to achieve what I need. I need a solution where we can still tokenize the value within the code but it is able to retrieve the secret values (db password etc) from the external properties file.

As you can imagine hard-coding these values or even just encrypting them wouldn't solve the issue due to the changing values between environments. We are able to retrieve the values within the application however I feel this is done too late in the process as Liquibase will have already attempted to start (and therefore fail) before the application code is run.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have full example at hand hence the comment, you need to most likely implement `ApplicationContextInitializer` in a class that can read those external properties file from the container and then inject them as spring properties in the applicationContext.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will take a look and update the question if I get any joy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution we took in the end. Effectively we worked out that the spring properties file could look directly in an external properties file (the csi driver in this case) to get the value.

Added to Spring properties file  `spring.config.import=optional:configtree:${env_var_for_external_property_file_location:#{null}}/liquibase/`

For clarity, below is the secret provider class yaml which stores the liquibase password. The object alias value matching what Liquibase config expects for db password.

```
  apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
   kind: SecretProviderClass
   metadata:
     name: name
   spec:
     provider: azure
     parameters:
       keyvaultName: ****
       tenantId: ****
       objects:  |
         array:
           - |
             objectName: lqb
             objectAlias: liquibase/spring.liquibase.password
             objectType: secret
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a method like this for a similar problem.

I'm running things on Jenkins server. But it's not necessary

I do not keep database connection information in files. After I send the files to the server, I add the database connection information to these files with bash script. The DB connection information is on the server, not the version control system.

Thus, I hide some db connection information from unauthorized people (only those who have access to the server can access it).

A- File example; liquibase.prod.properties
there is no db data

```
changeLogFile=./master.xml
logFile: liquibase.prod.log
logLevel: INFO
liquibase.hub.mode=off
```

B- Example of file where I keep database connections on server

```
spring.liquibase.url = my_env_db_connection_url
spring.liquibase.user= my_env_db_lb_username
spring.liquibase.password= my_env_db_lb_password
```

C- I am adding lines to this file with Jenkins and cmd bash

```
type E:\file1.cfg >> file2.cfg
```